# Mass Transit: multiple subscribers to one consumer

Tags: .net, masstransit, servicebus

we have **Payment microservice** which has a **consumer** called **CollectPayment**
and there is a feature service called **Groceries Service** that send a **command** called **CollectPaymentCommand**

this command is fetched by payment microservice and then payment microservice publish **PaymentCollectedEvent**

there is a **groceries state machine** that subscribe to PaymentCollectedEvent and then update the groceries request status

[image]
Now we have a new feature microservice called **Fuel microservice** that wants to communicate with payment microservice.

so it will send CollectPaymentCommand which will be fetched by payment microservice and then payment microservcie publishes PaymentCollectedEvent

there is a **fuel state machine** that will subscribe to **PaymentCollectedEvent** and then update the Fuel request status

**so, now we will have two subscribers to same event, which means each one will receive other service events.**

should we have two seperate consumers into payment microservice **(CollectFuelPayment && CollectGroceriesPayment)** along with **(FuelPaymentCollected && GroceriesPaymentCollected)** to handle each feature separately and incase I want to have one consumer **(CollectPayment)** inside payment microservice, what will be the other solutions?

Comment: why not creating an interface that listen to the event ond then create two classes the implemnts the interface. Then in runtime you inject the client or the service or the implemntation u want. https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_polymorphism.php

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an architectural flaw in your system.

1. Groceries shouldn't be requesting payment, the state machine should to ensure the payment is only requested once.
2. The payment should be requested, with the response sent to the originator (the saga) to mark the payment completed.

That way, each new domain concern (fuel vs groceries) would have its own state machine and its own request to the payment service (to which the payment service would *respond* to advance the state machine). A separate event published that a payment was completed would not be used by the state machine but could be outside of that for auditing, etc.

Comment: Does that mean, we need to create 2 commands (CollectGroceriesPayment and CollectFuelPayment) and have 2 consumers at the Payments microservice and each consumer would then emit a different Event to advance the saga (GroceriesPaymentCollected and FuelPaymentCollected)? the concern is that both Consumers will do the exact same operation (potentially anti Dry), and does that mean that whenever we add a new domain microservice, we have to add a new consumer to collect payment in Payments microservice?

Comment: The payment service owns the contracts (collect payment, payment collected) and the sagas are clients of that service and use those contracts.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, sorry it could be the language barrier, what I got from the first answer to the question is that I should have two separate consumers in payments service to reply to each saga and if I add a third saga (Car wash), I’ll add a 3rd consumer in payments service and deploy both services. From the last comment I got that payments service should be agnostic of the sender and have one consumer to collect payment and publish payment collected, by correlation Id, the non concerned saga will skip the message, could you please elaborate more?